# Performance Issue with Linq query while checking filter text in Contains method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, query-performance

I m trying to execute the below Linq Query , but the thing is when i'm executing below Linq Query with the Search query text , im getting sql timeout all the times. please suggest better way to optimize this . My Db table has nearly half million records.

```
{
            QueryBuilder = (from ub in idamDbContext.UserBasicInfo
                            join ur in idamDbContext.UserRoles on ub.UserId equals ur.UserBasicInfoId
                            join r in idamDbContext.Role on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                            join urt in idamDbContext.UserType on r.UserTypeId equals urt.Id
                            where (r.UserTypeId == 1 || r.UserTypeId == 3 || r.UserTypeId == 2) &&
                            (territoryId == null || ub.TerritoryId == territoryId) &&
                            (centerId == null || ub.CenterId == centerId) &&
                            (isActive == null || ub.IsActive == isActive)
                            orderby ub.Created
                            select new UserProfileDTO
                            {
                                UserId = ub.UserId,
                                UserName = ub.UserName,
                                FirstName = ub.FirstName,
                                LastName = ub.LastName,
                                Email = ub.Email,
                                TerritoryId = ub.TerritoryId,
                                UserTypeId = r.UserTypeId,
                                Description = r.Description,
                                Name = urt.Name
                            }
                   );

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
                QueryBuilder = QueryBuilder.Where(x => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.FirstName) && x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(query)) ||
                (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.LastName) && x.LastName.ToLower().Contains(query)) ||
                (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email) && x.Email.ToLower().Contains(query)) ||
                (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Description) && x.Description.ToLower().Contains(query)) ||
                (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.UserName) && x.UserName.ToLower().Contains(query)) ||
                (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) && x.Name.ToLower().Contains(query))
                );
        }
```

Comment: question asked was too broad. Please be specific on the problem and what you expect ?

Comment: You need to increase the time in the SQL Command object.  The database object has a property CommandTimeOut which defaults to 30 seconds.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Did you check if tables has proper indexes?

Comment: Use a tool like Linqpad or run a trace to see what sql the linq query generates. Then run the sql in SSMS and examine the execution plan.

Comment: As others said, examine the SQL sent to database.